# How can I import an enum from another package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, enums

Apparently, the provided enum is not the right one (even if I let Intellij autoimport it):

[image]

Please excuse the black line, I had to hide sensitive data.

```
import my.company.tools.backup.checking.external.persistence.core.Persistence.HibernateConnectionProperty 

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getHibernateConnectionPropertyName(HibernateConnectionProperty.USERNAME);
    }
}
```

Even clicking on the enum leads me to its declaration so I'm a bit confused.

I'm using Intellij Ultimate 2020.3; Java 11 (Adopt Open JDK).

Cleaning cache didn't work.

Comment: Is this the enum created by you? You can try to use Persistence.HibernateConnectionProperty.USERNAME.

Comment: Can this be that you have several versions of this enum on the classpath?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow, post text rather than images wherever practical.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Serguey Shinder suggested, I had several versions in my class path. In this project exist multiple POMs and parent POMs. One of them had indeed a package as dependency with the exact code I put into the project. Therefore, the IDE was confused which enum to take.

To figure out those transitive dependencies I used `mvn dependency:tree` to get a full list of ALL denpendencies and the full inheritance.

Thank you very much dear community!